# Out of bounds after using char to upper case

Tags: java

Having trouble with a Simple Selection code, my first year in BCIS. I am not sure what to do with this error.

It goes through the compiler without a problem, allows me to enter the Name, Account number and Balance but after that, it crashes and displays the error mentioned below.

Having trouble figuring out what could be causing it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problem1
{
   public void run()
   {

    //Declaring Variables

    String name;
    int number = 0;
    double balance = 0;
    double interest = 0;
    char type;
    String acType;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    final double CHEQ = 0.005;
    final double SAV = 0.0125;
    final double GIC = 0.0085;
    final double TFSA = 0.0075;

    //Input user parameters

    System.out.println("Please Enter the Account Name:");
    name = kb.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please Enter the Account Number:");
    number = kb.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please Enter the Account Balance:");
    balance = kb.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please Enter the Account Type");
    acType = kb.nextLine();

    System.out.println();
    type = acType.toUpperCase().charAt(0);

    //Processing the input values

    switch (type)
    {
    case 'C':
        interest = CHEQ * balance;
        break;
    case 'S':
        interest = SAV * balance;
        break;
    case 'G':
        interest = GIC * balance;
        break;
    case 'T':
        interest = TFSA * balance;
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Error: Please enter a valid Accout Type");

    }

    //Output the provided and calculated information

    System.out.format("Account Name:        %-10s", name);
    System.out.format("%nAccount Number:    %-5d", number);

    System.out.format("%nAccount Balance:   $  %-5.2", balance);
    System.out.format("%nAccount Type:      %-10s", type);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.format("Interest Amount:     $ %-5.2", interest);
}
}
```

It always gives me an error that it is out of Bounds.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
 String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
    at Problem1.run(Problem1.java:36)
    at Client.main(Client.java:6)
```

Comment: you know java is not javascript right? It literally shows when you hover over the tag of javascript but you can't read that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because a couple of your calls to grab user input do NOT clear the end of line character that comes after you enter a number. You can clear it right after by calling the nextLine() method.

Try something like this

```
System.out.println("Please Enter the Account Name:");
name = kb.nextLine();

System.out.println("Please Enter the Account Number:");
number = kb.nextInt();
kb.nextLine(); //clear the end of line

System.out.println("Please Enter the Account Balance:");
balance = kb.nextDouble();
kb.nextLine(); //clear the end of line

System.out.println("Please Enter the Account Type");
acType = kb.nextLine();

System.out.println();
type = acType.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
```